# How can I obtain specific row from python mysql database by using a value stored in a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, pymysql

My code goes here:

```
def draw_money():
    dr_list = [acc_num, acc_num_entry, with_btn, with_money,with_money_entry]

    for i in dr_list:
        i.destroy()

    new_acc = acc_num_var.get()
    money_amount = money.get()

    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", password="", db="bankac")
    cur = con.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM ac WHERE name = new_acc"
    cur.execute(query)`
```

**But when I am executing this function I am getting the following error---**

```
*Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\Documents\app\bank.py", line 33, in draw_money
    cur.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\AMISHA SINGH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'new_acc' in 'where clause'")*
```

Please help me. I have tried many ways but I am not able to figure it out. I am working on a bank simulation using python modules tkinter and pymysql. I want to obtain a specific row from the database  by comparing a value stored in a python variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable using parameter substitution, like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ac WHERE name = %s"
cur.execute(query, (new_acc,))
```

Note that the value parameter(s) passed to execute must be a in tuple or list, even if there is only one of them.  `(new_acc,)` is a single element tuple.

It's also possible to pass values in a dictionary, using a slightly different substitution:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ac WHERE name = %(var_name)s"
cur.execute(query, {'var_name': new_acc})
```

Comment: but if there is more than one item, then tuple is not required right ?

Comment: @CoolCloud   No, you still need a tuple/list:  `cur.execute(query, (val1, val2))`.  `cur.execute(query, val1, val2)` results in a `TyeError`.

Comment: not like that, like saying `values = val1,val2` and then `cur.execute(query, values))`